# Where to ask about law, morality and ethics?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

I wanted to know how could I properly tag a question, if my question is about, legal and ethics, about a project I'm doing.

I searched about similar questions, but couldn't find any similar.

Could it be in another stack? from stack exchange, or should I open a discussion?

Comment: It would be off-topic in Stack Overflow. To suggest an alternative site, we would need to know more about your question.

Comment: wow, I've been in stack overflow for a while, and I never knew that, I mean I get why, It's off topic, but, still, it feels odd, but If it were on topic, It would be a bunch of posts related to that... I get it.

Comment: I did the question on Law [link](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/32471/legality-of-using-library-genesis-or-related-tools)

Comment: twitter is the go-to place for these kinds of questions

Comment: If you want to know *where on Stack Exchange* to ask a question, then that is a topic for meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This question is fine here, since it's asking about, among other things, _this site's scope_.  That could include recommending other Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 13):

Legal and ethical questions are off topic for Stack Overflow.

[Law SE](http://law.stackexchange.com) is for legal questions, but note that **asking for legal advice on a specific matter is explicitly off topic**. See also [their help center](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

**Ethics** would be on topic on [Philosophy](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com). Although that's about ethics in general. If you're wondering about the ethics of a specific decision, that may or may not be a good fit for that site. There is also some element of ethics on a lot of the more subjective sites (e.g. on [Workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) you can ask about the [ethics](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethics) of workplace-related decisions).

**Regarding licenses**, see [Where can I ask about Software Licenses/Licensing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165980/where-can-i-ask-about-software-licenses-licensing). If you have a specific not-too-complex question about a specific well-known license, that may be on topic somewhere (like the [Open Source SE](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) in the case of open source software). But asking for a license recommendation would probably be off topic.

Comment: well, It's no actual legal, It's more to get a "brief" panorama, if It's right or wrong, and If its doable choose a license,
It's for a software project I have, nothing big, but I have the feeling IT could be "wrong" and if it is I don't want to even start it. 
In legal, Is still the correct one?

Comment: Right or wrong (instead of legal and illegal) would be off topic for Law. Helping you choose a licence is presumably also off topic for that site.

Comment: @ekiim As far as your choice of licence is concerned, https://opensource.stackexchange.com might be relevant if it would be an open-source one -- but please do check [their help center](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking there.

Comment: *Some* questions about ethics might be on-topic on Philosophy.SE, but I'd suspect this sort of question would not be.

Comment: @ekiim It sounds like you may want to instead use a resource like [TLDRLegal](https://tldrlegal.com/) for understanding software licenses. Note that the site language is not a replacement for the actual text of a license, but aims to give a more simplified explanation of the requirements and privileges of different software licenses without the legal jargon. Also note that the site is **not** a replacement for legal counsel for making an *actual* legal decision. You would want a (company-employed-or-retained) lawyer to make any legal determinations on the business' behalf.